# unable to install windows 10 sdk for holo lens

Tags: visual-studio-2015, hololens

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OF5E.png)

failed attempts

1. tried installing windows 10 sdk through iso
2. tried installing through official holo lens.

please any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: What versions of Windows are you on?  Windows 10?  If Windows 10, which one? What Visual Studio 2015 are you on?  Is it Update 3?

Comment: maybe try the standalone SDK?  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: i am using windows 10 pro and visual studio 2015 update 3 community edition @CameronVetter